# What is the opposite of "grep"?

Tags: grep

Say I'm printing out a long series of strings, and instead of only showing lines containing a certain pattern (which one uses "grep" to do), how do I **filter out** certain patterns?

Comment: `grep -v pattern files*`

Comment: @lcd047 - Thanks! I guess I should have read the instruction for grep, rather than look for a separate command. Btw, since you commented before the other answerer did, I'd accept your answer if you posted it as one.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You still use grep... with the `-v` option, which tells grep to print only those lines which do **not** match the pattern:

```
grep -v pattern myfile
```

The long form of the `-v` option is `--invert-match` (mnemonic: "in**v**ert match").

Comment: The long form of the flag `-v` is `--invert-match`.